# Expected Levenshtein distance between two random binary strings

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, expected-value, combinatorics-on-words

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are randomly chosen from binary strings of length $n$ with uniform distribution. What is the expected [Levenshtein distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between them?

All I currently know is, that it does not exceed the expected Hamming distance which is $\frac{n}{2}$.

If the exact formula is too complicated, I would like to see the asymptotic for $n \to \infty$.

Comment: The expected Hamming distance is $\frac n2$.

Comment: A related question has been asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128903/expected-edit-distance).